# When XML is empty, xcode crashes - Possible to insert dummy object?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xml

I got more of a general question. Instead of a tableview I have a normal view with Buttons and Labels. Three of each. If I have exactly three objects in my database and parsed them into XML, the VC shows them to me. But if I only have two objects in the XML, xcode crashes because of

```
'*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 0 beyond bounds for empty array'
```

which makes sense, because one label/button stays empty though it is expecting three. 
I tried working around by telling it only to fill buttons and labels if the object is there.

```
if ( object1 != nil)
```

But this might be too easy. I was thinking of putting dummy objects into my database. Then again I have to delete them everytime when a real one comes in and vice versa.

So maybe encountered this problem aswell and has a solution or an idea?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why would you want to complicate the problem?  Checking for nil is a perfectly acceptable solution.

Comment: Well I check for nil, but it still says "NO ITS EMPTY, I CRASH" :)

Comment: Then you also need to check the length of the array to make sure it has content ^^

Comment: Thanks, then I might do something wrong while telling him what to do, when it's empty.

Answer (score 1):

Checking for nil is a good way to do this.  If your array is initialized and empty, then you need to check the count also.

Like so:

```
if( (array != nil) && ([array count] > 0) ) {
    //do something
}
```